# Getting 500 server error just in the index page of laravel

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, plesk

I am newbie to the plesk panel. The problem I am having is, I am only getting 500 server error in the index page. Other page of the same website opens perfectly except index. There is a following code in the .htaccess file of my project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

What should I do to make the index page work like other pages? Do I have to add codes to .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the index.php. The issue is about permissioning.

Execute

```
sudo chmod -R 755 folderforaccess
```

and

```
chmod -R o+w folderforaccess/storage
```

On live server you can do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

then also make sure that the php version in your composer.json is the same as that of your server.

Check your php version in your terminal using php -v

Comment: How can I do this in live server?

Comment: Updated the answer for query about live server

Comment: Are you unable to SSH to your server?

Comment: I can access other page except index. What does php version in your composer.json is the same as that of your server means? I have higher php version in my server. Do you mean I have to have same php version in composer.json?

Comment: Yes that what it means. But its an afterthought. The first order of the day is to find out if you can access your server over SSH or not. I believe that you can. Whose your hosting provider? Once you SSH to your server, all you need to do is to run the above command. Upvote the answer please else the query would be closed!